# Migração de site para outro servidor

Tags: microsoft-azure

Atualmente, tenho um site hospedado no UOL Host (i3t.com.br) e preciso migrar esse site para o Azure host.

Eu criei uma aplicação web no portal Azure, configurei o servidor FTP e fiz o upload do meu site usando o programa WinSCP. Até aqui tudo certo, porém preciso configurar o DNS para que eu consiga acessar o site pela URL i3t.com.br (ou www.i3t.com.br). No momento só consigo acessar o site pela URL sitei3t.azurewebsites.net/i3t/

Como não tenho muita experiência com esse tipo de configuração e acho o portal do Azure meio complicado, não sei como fazer isso. Alguém teria alguma dica para eu resolver esse problema?

Comment: aproveitando que você está mudando de host do uol, não sei se você teve uma experiencia negativa com esse host, fica aqui a minha dica: https://www.linode.com/pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente verifique o *Service Plan* do aplicativo (*resource*) que utilizou para hospedar seu site no Azure. Provavelmente o resource que está usando é um Web App.

Se o *Service Plan* que está utilizando no seu resource possuir um *Pricing Tier* (camada de preço) **F1 (Free)**, você não tem direito a um *custom domain* (domínio customizado).

Para ter acesso a um *custom domain*, o seu *Service Plan* deve possuir um *Pricing Tier* superior ao F1 (Free): D1 Shared, B1 Basic, B2 Basic, B3 Basic, P1 Premium, etc.

## Pricing Tiers disponíveis para os apps/resources do Azure

Note que os *custom domains* começam a aparecer a partir do D1 Shared.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso tenha o Pricing Tear adequado, faça o seguinte:

## 1. Custom domains

Dentro do seu *resource/app*, selecione a opção *Custom domains*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## 2. Hostname

Na tela aberta, clique em *Add hostname*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela aberta, digite o nome do domínio que deseja utilizar e clique em validar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se a validação estiver OK, irão aparecer os passos de como configurar seu domínio. Siga os passos e pronto.

Se surgirem dúvidas sobre como configurar o domínio, acesse o seguinte link: [Configurar domínio Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas estou esbarrando em alguns problemas técnicos como CNAME e TXT. Você saberia me dizer se isso seria porque o domínio foi registrado na UOL? Eu não teria que configurar uma zona de DNS? Realmente sou muito novo nisso.

Comment: No seu caso terá que usar o CNAME, para redirecionar o domínio. E essa configuração deve ser feita no domínio do UOL. Segue link para ajuda: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name

Comment: @BrenoMacena Conseguiu?

Comment: consegui sim! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Opa, maravilha! Feliz em ajudar!